# ASP.NET MVC Individual user accounts configuration

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I want to create an application that uses individual user accounts identity functionality of MVC. I also want to harness this functionality in order to extend the application so I can add new fields to the register page so that it populates not only the AspNetUsers Table, but also to a custom table that I had made locally within Visual Studio called Customers. I've set up the table so that the customer table has a foreign key field for the GUID that is produced when a ASPNetUser is created. So far, ive found it challenging as I dont really know where to start and find other tutorials I found not really answering my question.

Does anyone have any tips? is this going to be harder than starting an MVC application and then adding in identity functionality afterwards in order to achieve this goal?

Thanks

Comment: Is this .Net framework or .net Core?

Comment: This is .NET Framework.

Comment: Ok. Articles like this should start to point you in the right direction: https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2016/02/01/customize-authentication.aspx?m=1 . Just make sure they are about asp.net and not asp.net core because the implementations are significantly different